# Qt font OS X and FontBook

Tags: macos, qt, fonts

I noticed this problem using Qt libraries, but, to be honest, than I found that is a global OS X issue. I have a music font, say the classic Petrucci.ttf or Marl.ttf... As I put characters using QPainter::drawText() function, I can see only standard letters.

Also this happens using asian fonts or other symbolic fonts. The same Qt code compiled on Windows can render the fonts in a correct way. So, for instance, the letter "a" is a note or a pause, or a clef...

In Mac, letter "a" remains an "a".

The strange thing is that if I open the font in the Font Book, the font is rendered correctly. So I also tried to use it on OpenOffice, Pages or TextEdit. Always on Mac symbolic fonts are rendered normally, typed letters remain letters.

Do you have any suggestions??

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, one answer I found is to check the entire font map and grab the unicode value of the range of interest. For example, for the font I'm using is 0xf021-0xf0fb, so, you can draw a non text symbol like this:

```
char c = 0xf021;
QString str = QString( QChar( c ) ); 
painter.drawText( 10, 10, str );
```